# Transform multiple arrays into one array?

Tags: php

I have 3 arrays, and each array contains other arrays with different internal values. However the values ​​of the first arrays are the same.

How could I concatenate, transform the 3 arrays into just one? I'm doing a translation logic

```
START:

$header = [
    "en" => [
        "home",
        "contact",
        "about"
    ],
    "pt" => [
        "Inicio",
        "contato",
        "sobre"
    ],
];

$main = [
    "en" => [
        "Wellcome to my Website",
        "This is a h2"
    ],
    "pt" => [
        "Bem vindo ao meu Website",
        "isto é um h2"
    ],
];

$footer = [
    "en" => [
        "I'm footer",
        "I'm a"
    ],
    "pt" => [
        "Sou o rodape",
        "sou a"
    ],
];
```

```
DESIRED RESULT:

$content = [
    "en" => [
        "home",
        "contact",
        "about",
        "Wellcome to my Website",
        "This is a h2",
        "I'm footer",
        "I'm a"
    ],
    "pt" => [
        "Inicio",
        "contato",
        "sobre",
        "Bem vindo ao meu Website",
        "isto é um h2",
        "Sou o rodape",
        "sou a"
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the desired result looks strange, but this code will do it:

```php
$content = [];
foreach ($header as $idx => $val) {
    $content[$idx] = array_merge($header[$idx], $main[$idx], $footer[$idx]);
}
```

Comment: I need this result for the translations on the page itself. each page has its own main, but the header and footer are always the same, for each element that contains the attribute eg data-translate you make an innerText in this content with the values ​​of the array, your code is great, I don't know how not I thought about it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
  $main = [
    "en" => [
        "Wellcome to my Website",
        "This is a h2"
    ],
    "pt" => [
        "Bem vindo ao meu Website",
        "isto é um h2"
    ],
];

$footer = [
    "en" => [
        "I'm footer",
        "I'm a"
    ],
    "pt" => [
        "Sou o rodape",
        "sou a"
    ],
];
$merged = array_merge($main, $footer);
```

Comment: As a result it should gather them all, but not